Reproducible anomalous R behavior in converting character vector to numeric - bug?
I have an R workflow in which I convert rownames in a dataframe to a vector of numeric values and use this vector to subset other objects. When I use the vector to subset, however, it returns different object items than it should. In this example, it treats '29' in my vector as if it is a '28'. This is the only number where I have found this issue.
Here is a dataframe with rownames:
df=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=2,nrow=50))
rownames(df)=c(1:50)/100
rownames(df)

Then convert those rownames to a numeric vector and use this vector to subset another numeric vector:
n=as.numeric(rownames(df))*100
n
v=1:50
v
v[n]



1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

Printing the vector 'n' results in as-expected 1:50 values. BUT - subsetting 'v' by 'n' (v[n]) results in the number '28' being selected twice (and '29' not at all).
This can be fixed by rounding n:
v[round(n)]


1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

But this doesn't make sense, because 'n' and 'round(n)' appear to be equal:
all.equal(n,round(n))


TRUE

One clue might be that n is numeric rather than (like v) an integer, or maybe this doesn't matter
class(n)


"numeric"

What is the deal? I can of course just add 'round()', but I'm worried about this issue (or bug?) popping up in other places if I don't understand it. Thanks!

This is a repeat of R FAQ 7.31.  The problem is that 29/100 can't be represented as a floating point value.  The all.equal() function tests for approximate equality; try identical() or == and you'll see the difference.

Another way to see the issue:  try computing ((1:50)/100)*100 - (1:50) and see that not all the values are zero

Ok, thank you, that all makes sense! Another piece of the puzzle that still had me confused but that I eventually figured out:
(1:50)[28.999] returns 28. I had assumed trying to subset with a non-integer would throw an error.
